# How to rent a car where the second driver cannot be present at rental pickup time?

Tags: usa, canada, car-rentals

I'm living in Vancouver and would like to rent a car and go on a road trip with a friend from Seattle. Local car rentals usually allow at least one extra driver for free, but the standard requirement is for both drivers to show up at the rental desk. In my particular scenario this is inconvenient as I want to pick up a car at YVR airport and head down to Washington to go pick up my friend.

Is it possible to somehow circumvent this requirement and have the second driver be added to the insurance without showing up in person? Question is limited to major car rental companies in North America to reduce the scope.

Comment: Have you asked any of the rental companies themselves?

Comment: "without showing up in person "....   you simply cannot do this - in the US it's impossible

Comment: @Fattie: Yes you can, I've done this, twice. You rent the car in your name only, then have to come back on whatever date your friend is there and modify the rental agreement to add them.

Comment: ok that's the **whole point** of what folks are saying, @smci.  right - you have to come back with the friend (to any branch of the company), walk the friend in to the office, and you can then do it.  it is absolutely impossible to do it "without showing up in person".

Comment: Fattie: you *can* rent the car. Just not in both drivers' names. The question title doesn't explicitly require that. But yeah you can't add them mid-trip, without physically going to some rental office (usually but not always the one you rented from) and modifying the contract.

Comment: Any office, and many are downtown so you don't have to go to the airport.  In fact the downtown offices will be far less busy.  And one of the few places in downtown where you can park for free (for that purpose).

Comment: " Is it possible to somehow circumvent this requirement **and have the second driver be added** without the second driver ***showing up in person?*** "  It is absolutely impossible to circumvent this requirement.  The second driver does have to **SHOW UP IN PERSON** at any office of that rental company.   What a confusing QA!  :)

Comment: This only applies if you're using the rental agency's insurance. If you're using the insurance provided as a feature of your credit card, then anyone you allow to drive the vehicle is covered. It's in the fine print of the credit card policy, but I've done this a number of times, and have confirmed it with the CC company.

Comment: @GregL care to add your answer?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yeah, sure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The requirement for the additional driver to be present is there because the agent must verify that s/he is in fact licensed to drive and matches the identity on the driver's license.

As such, to do everything strictly by the book, you would rent the car solo, drive to pick up your friend, then stop at the nearest branch of the rental agency. There, your travel companion would be added to the rental agreement. For example, [Alamo's Additional Driver Policy](https://www.alamo.com/en_US/car-rental-faqs/additional-driver.html) states

> An additional driver may only be added to the contract at a rental location and may be added or removed in the middle of the contract. **When adding an additional driver in the middle of the contract both the renter and the additional driver must be present at the location.**
>
> The system will calculate the charges based on the dates the additional driver was listed on the rental.

(emphasis in original)

Comment: it's interesting point you **BOTH** have to be present, when adding someone in the middle.

Comment: One exception alluded to in your link is some types of corporate rentals, where a special agreement applies. For example, when they rent vans at work, they automatically authorize all employees; somebody from our company goes and gets them and hands over the keys to drivers. Said agreement also drops the age limit to 18. However, I doubt this is going to help the OP.

Comment: "it's interesting point you BOTH have to be present, when adding someone in the middle."  Presumably you had to drive the car to the middle location; if you're not there, it would imply that you broke the rental agreement by having the extra person drive themselves. It'd be interesting if you had two people initially on the rental and wanted to add another. Do both of the initial people need to be present?

Comment: hey @RogerLipscombe, lol right - what I had in mind is in a city depot person A could wander off to Starbucks, leaving person B to the annoying line and paperwork.  The three-body problem you raise is intriguing, heh!  :)

Comment: @RogerLipscombe No, it's not implied that the driver to be added drove the car to the location. It could have been a *different* additional driver that is not the renter. The presence of the renter probably has more to do with the renter's permission to add the additional driver.

Comment: I have done exactly this. All but the smallest, most local rental companies have branches in all the major cities, frequently several branches.

Comment: @Fattie Well, not everyone bothers to add the second driver to the agreement. Given how litigious the U.S. is, I would always recommend travelers try to do things "the right way" of course, but not everyone is going to follow every requirement to the letter.

Comment: hi @choster  AH - I totally see what you mean, sorry.   You're suggesting, of course, some folks would just go ahead and "let someone else drive" without being on the agreement.   Yes, of course you're correct, some folks do that (and it's a bad idea).  nice one.

Comment: Interesting, I would presume that a driving license (perhaps with other docs) is exactly what is needed to evaluate whether someone is **licensed** to drive. Unless they want to evaluate other aspects (whether a person is fit to drive, for instance, and willing to accept liability for damages), it should not take the presence of the person to determine 'licenced-ness'.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin The agent at a minimum needs to verify that the person presenting the license is the same person whose name and photo is on it.

Answer (score 5):

I've asked a rental car company about this. I was told that the second person had to be present, however, "if the second person happened to be stuck at the airport collecting luggage or something, and I happened to have their driving licence, they'd add them". In other words, they'd let me add a second person if I had their driving licence with me and made up a story that they were nearby.

Can the other person fedex their licence to you or something? If so, you could try that.

Alternatively, if the rental car company has offices in the US, they will let you add the second person at another office if you turn up with them. I've done that before on several occasions.

Comment: that does seem exceptionally unusual, @Berwyn - was this many years ago??

Comment: "they will let you add the second person at another office if you turn up with them." .. precisely

Comment: This strikes me as a rather risky strategy.

Comment: @Fattie The first scenario was a few weeks ago when I asked about adding my wife without her having to go to the rental car place, and adding a second driver at another office - I last did that last year in the US with a colleague

Comment: Spouses are usually exempt or handled differently under rental agreements.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here, and the question too for that matter, seem to assume that you're going to use the rental agency's loss damage waiver, and in my experience, they're accurate.

However, most "premium" credit cards (MC World, MC World Elite, etc...) have a "Travel Protection" benefit which covers you, and any drivers you authorize, to drive the vehicle. For example the [CIBC credit card insurance states](https://www.cibc.com/content/dam/personal_banking/credit_cards/agreements_and_insurance/auto-rental-ins-en.pdf) that:

> (2) Any other person who drives the same rental vehicle with Your permission
>   **whether or not such person has been listed on the rental vehicle contract or
>   has been identified to the Rental Agency at the time of making the rental**,
>   however, You and all drivers must otherwise qualify under and follow the
>   terms of the rental contract and must be legally licensed and permitted to
>   drive the rental vehicle under the laws of the jurisdiction in which the rental
>   vehicle shall be used.

Generally they'll ask you to book, and pay for, the rental on said credit card, and specifically decline the agency's LDW.

Not all classes of vehicles are covered, and the terms can vary by issuer, so it's best to get a copy of them, to confirm if your card provides the benefit, and what's required to be covered.

Comment: Accepting this answer for a creative solution. I actually do have a credit card with LDW coverage.

Comment: Surely you still need the permission of the rental company to allow other drivers than yourself to drive the vehicle?  For example, there may be age restrictions set by the rental company or other restrictions not insurance related.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanReez! I once got a no-cost Capital One card, just for this feature, because my main card didn't have it. But if you travel a lot, the cost of the premium card is probably worth it, because rental agency's LDWs can get expensive.

Comment: @Moo, obviously the other drivers would need to qualify as valid drivers in the location you're driving (of age, have a licence, etc..). However, no, you don't need the permission from, or to disclose to, the agency if you intend to have other people drive the vehicle.

Comment: @GregL are you sure about that?  Its still their vehicle and their property, they have the right to say who can and cannot drive it, regardless of what your independent insurance covers...

Comment: Suppose the second driver gets stopped by police and they ask for proof of insurance. How's that going to work? Suppose you're not with them?

Comment: Just to clarify, what the rental company is selling you isn't insurance, but rather a "loss/damage waiver". They've covered their cars with a rental policy that doesn't include named drivers because it realistically can't. The waiver you're buying covers you (and others you name) in the event that you get into an accident, or the vehicle is damaged or stolen. What the credit card company has as part of their benefit is the same thing, only you don't have to provide the rental company names, and you can decline their coverage. A number of personal car insurance policies offer the same thing.

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS WRONG, at least in a general sense. With a few exceptions (which vary based on the rental company, the state/country, and any corporate plans being used), a secondary driver needs to be explicitly listed on the contract, which requires presenting their license at a rental location.  Even Credit Card insurance will not cover if you are in breach of the rental contract, which is what would be occurring if an unauthorized driver was driving the vehicle.

Comment: This is not a good idea. If the other driver is not authorized by the rental company, they could be [suspected of stealing the car](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/12562090-post14.html) if they're stopped for a traffic violation. Allowing an unauthorized driver to drive the car will violate your rental agreement. The likelihood of it becoming a problem may not be that great, but if it does result in a problem, it could be an extremely large one. Don't let unauthorized drivers take the wheel of your rental just because you have a credit card.

Comment: Indeed, an unauthorized rental car driver recently [sparked a Supreme Court case](http://www.scotusblog.com/2018/05/opinion-analysis-justices-rule-unanimously-for-driver-in-rental-car-case/) after the police believed they could search the vehicle without a warrant or consent because the driver was unauthorized. It turns out the police can't do that. But the point is that police are well aware of the concept of authorized drivers of rental cars, and you do not want to be on the wrong end of that discussion.

Comment: @Doc, if the secondary drivers need to be listed on the rental agreement, why does the passage from the credit card terms specifically state that it doesn't matter if they are? Seems like denying coverage for being in breach of the rental contract, while simultaneously providing text that states it's fine makes no sense.

Comment: @ZachLipton Those linked articles are both interesting reads, but they're US cases, and I'm not sure if any of that applies to rentals in Canada, which is the context for the question, and where my experience is based.

Comment: @GregL because not all drivers have a requirement to be listed.  eg, in many cases a spouse does not need to be listed to be an "authorized operator". Thus the statement "... all drivers must otherwise qualify under and follow the terms of the rental contract"